# Django reads images without defining MEDIA_URL

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I'm new to Django, I know that to display an image I should define `MEDIA_URL` in the settings.

But when I tried to remove it and use the `{{ img.url }}`  the images are still readable and the browser can see it and display it. The question is does this mean that the `MEDIA_URL` does not import in displaying images, and why did we declare it if we can use `img.url` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No images should not be viewable if you remove

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

from settings.py

and

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If they are, it is probably just because your browser cached the images.

Try doing CNTL + SHIFT + DEL while in your browser and clearing the cache. Then reload your django web page.